# c# drawing text over an object

Tags: c#

i am drawing a dashed line over an object using this method:

```
// Get Graphics object from chart
        Graphics graph = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;

        PointF point1 = PointF.Empty;
        PointF point2 = PointF.Empty;

        // Set Maximum and minimum points
        point1.X = -110;
        point1.Y = -110;
        point2.X = 122;
        point2.Y = 122;

        // Convert relative coordinates to absolute coordinates.
        point1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point1);
        point2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(point2);

        // Draw (dashed) connection line
       float[] dashValues = { 4, 2 };
       Pen dashPen= new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
       dashPen.DashPattern = dashValues;
       graph.DrawLine(dashPen, point1, point2);
```

and i would like to know whether it is possible to write text over an object the same way/.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this in [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx) method.